# Elasticsearch how to search by time in datetime field

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, time, range, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a imaginary index `test` with below mapping

```
PUT test
{"mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "endTs" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
          "index": true
        },
        "startTs" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
          "index": true
        }
      }
    }
}
```

And add some value like below

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test"} }
{ "startTs": "2020-01-01 00:00:00", "endTs": "2020-01-01 00:15:00" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test"} }
{ "startTs" : "2020-01-01 00:15:00", "endTs" : "2020-01-01 00:30:00" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test"} }
{ "startTs" : "2020-01-01 00:30:00", "endTs" : "2020-01-01 00:45:00" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test"} }
{ "startTs" : "2020-01-01 00:45:00", "endTs" : "2020-01-01 01:00:00" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test"} }
{ "startTs": "2020-01-01 01:00:00", "endTs": "2020-01-01 01:15:00" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test"} }
{ "startTs" : "2020-01-01 01:15:00", "endTs" : "2020-01-01 01:30:00" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test"} }
{ "startTs" : "2020-01-01 01:30:00", "endTs" : "2020-01-01 01:45:00" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test"} }
{ "startTs" : "2020-01-01 01:45:00", "endTs" : "2020-01-01 02:00:00" }
```

My goal is to run some range query within this `startTs` and `endTs` field. like `startTs: 2020-01-01 00:00:00'` and `endTs: 2020-01-01 00:45:00'`. I need to fo filter only with `time` not full `datetime` format. So I tried below filter

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "startTs": {
              "gte": "00:00:00",
              "format": "HH:mm:ss"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "endTs": {
              "lte": "00:45:00",
              "format": "HH:mm:ss"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I expected it will return all the record value less then equal to `2020-01-01 00:45:00`

```
{ "startTs": "2020-01-01 00:00:00", "endTs": "2020-01-01 00:15:00" }
{ "startTs" : "2020-01-01 00:15:00", "endTs" : "2020-01-01 00:30:00" }
{ "startTs" : "2020-01-01 00:30:00", "endTs" : "2020-01-01 00:45:00" }
```

But It didn't return anything at all.

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
```

Then I tried

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['startTs'].value.minute >= 0"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['endTs'].value.minute <= 45"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It return all the value that hase minute less than equal 45 and that is also not expected.

**How to run the query for the given index with time range?** any help is highly appreciated.

I am using *elasticsearch 7.6*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trail I found a solution.

It's working for me. Though I am not happy about it.

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['startTs'].value.hour * 60 + doc['startTs'].value.minute >= 0"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['endTs'].value.hour * 60 + doc['endTs'].value.minute <= 45"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Still looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of indexing a `date` type I suggest that you index an `integer` with the number of minutes or seconds (depends on the resolution you need) since the beginning of the day. Then run a range query against this field.

The `date` type doesn't support the type of query you want to do here.